# Monotouch binding ObjC library

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have an error while building fat binary:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 (or arm7 for device)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

even if I place only one defenition (AWView) in ApiDefinition. All dependencies were included.

Although, in xcode everything is ok.

Here is a link to [github](https://github.com/gaech/adwired-binding).

P.S. "xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info /...../libAdWired.a" tells that

> Architectures in the fat file: libAdWired.a are: i386 armv6 armv7

Answer (score 3):

I had to free my mind, and I love/enjoy doing MonoTouch bindings so please give this a try

https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.AdWired

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: As a side note, this library is kinda old so you should beware if you will be using it with iOS 6 which deprecated the usage of `UUID` in favor of `iOS 6 advertising identifier (IDFA)`. So I would recommend checking this directly with AdWired

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling for an actual device which will be targeting armv7 architecture.... Your objc library was not compiled with the i386 architecture in it, probably just armv7.  You can see which architectures are compiled in it by going to terminal and using the command:

```
file libSomeLibrary.a
```

This will tell you all the architectures in the compiled library.
So, simply choose Debug -> iPhone   instead of iPhone Simulator and you should not get that same error...

Comment: You could, alternatively, make sure you target i386 as well in your build of the library, if you have access to do so.

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: libAdWired.a are: i386 armv6 armv7